# Can't uninstall virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, sudo, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

So I installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` with `sudo pip`, and I have problems.  At first I was getting correct behavior, with packages from the virtual environment being separate from packages outside the virtual environment.  But then all of a sudden they merged and started being the same.  I tried uninstalling both packages, but now even though I can't see them in `pip`, I can still use the `workon` command, so I know that they're there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured out the answer, for anyone out there who has any issues that are similar.  When I rebooted, the `workon` command was gone.  So then I logged in as root and installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` from scratch. I exited root, and then was able to install packages with `pip` normally in my virtualenv, the key being that I not use `sudo`.  The use of `sudo` was messing everything up.  So I still don't understand it perfectly, but those steps worked for me.